# What is MVVM proper way to deal with “insertion”

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Here is my requirement (I am simplifying things for sake of this question). I have a list of people identified by first name and last name. The list is stored in the XML file. I need to build WPF app that consists of two windows: main windows displays the list. Nothing fancy, just a list with first name and last name. 
Three buttons on the bottom: Add, Edit, Delete.
When Delete button clicked the selected row is permanently deleted from the file.
When Add or Edit button is clicked the second window is popping up (a dialog) where you can respectively enter new person by typing her first and last name, or modify and persist existing record.

How do I build this app in MVVM proper way? Here are specific questions I have:

1) From MVVM point of view I cannot bind directly to XML data source, or can I? So I should create object Person that implements INotifyPropertyChange, then store bunch of this objects in ObservableCollection. Respectively I need to write code that reads XML file and converts it to collection of objects and vice versa when I need to save changes back into file. I am I right?

2) Where to I put "Persist" method implementation that actually saves into XML file? There are two places where this method would be called: clicking Delete button of main window, or clicking OK button of Add/Edit window.

3) Please note that the same window handles Add and Edit, how I do I implement this window in a proper MVVM way? How do I display title of that window "Add" or "Edit" respectively without resorting to ugly if statement i code behind? To what I bind two text boxes that I have there (first and last name). Please also note that Add/Edit window has OK and Cancel buttons, changes are not accepted until OK is clicked, and if Cancel is clicked the changes have to be discarded. One possible solution I see is to clone Person object rather than bind directly to the same object as list is bound so that list does not show changes until OK is clicked, but that is hairy as I need to write code to copy properties back and forth. Is there better way to do it in MVVM?
Thank in advance

Henry

Answer (score 2):

To address your three specific questions,

1/ If your View binds directly to XML then this isn't MVVM. A MVVM pattern would have your View bound to a ViewModel which presents the XML. If you don't need to alter the XML then there's no problem with directly binding, but because you are going to add/edit/delete values from the XML it makes sense to have the ViewModel controlling that interaction. I would indeed create a `Person` object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

2/ In MVVM all functional code goes in the ViewModel. This `Persist` button would fire a Command, which calls a method in the ViewModel. This is somewhat confusing at first, and not as simple as a code-behind 'click', but makes more sense from a dumb View / MVVM perspective. It's also cleaner.

3/ The 'Edit' screen will bind to a `Person` object, and will fire to a `Save` Command. This command should then performs the appropriate logic, determining whether it's a new (insert) or existing (update) record. If the object is new then the parent ViewModel (you'll want a ViewModel for the collection, rather than just an ObservableCollection) needs to catch that event and add the new object to the collection.

In addition the 'Edit/Add' window can return a result, and the parent ViewModel can investigate that result after the window has closed, then determining what to do (save/discard, edit/add, any other validation etc).

Here are some links:

- [The MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) - great MSDN article for a MVVM introduction
- [How to implement MVVM, ICommand etc](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/how-to-implement-mvvm-inotifychanged-and-icommand-in-a-silverlight-application/) - implementing ICommand
- [MVVM Command Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852084/mvvm-command-binding) - more on binding to Commands.

Comment: RE #2, I use RelayCommand and define my commands as properties within the ViewModel itself.  That makes it a little less confusing, doesn't require as many Classes, and allow access to other ViewModel properties to boot.

Comment: @JoelCochran Indeed - I didn't mean to imply that the Command wasn't in the ViewModel, just that it in turn calls a method in the ViewModel. In my projects everything to which the View binds is in the ViewModel.